# Enumitem \SetEnumitemKey and conflict between multiple key before and after

Tags: enumitem, key-value

I try to make life easier by setting key to list with the package `enumitem`.
But, the options `before` and `after` seem to be in conflict when used more than once.

Here is some code that show four examples:

- the first uses only the key `cols`,
- the second only the key `dots`,
- the third, which is the one which does not work as expected, uses first the key `cols` and then the key `dots`,
- and the last use also the two keys but in the other order and work nice.

I am wondering why the third does not work but the last works fine.

Maybe there is a conflict with the use of `before` and `after` twice...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage[a4paper, top=0.5cm, bottom=1.6cm, left=0.7cm , right=0.7cm]{geometry}
\parindent0cm
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\auxpts}[0]{\makebox[\linewidth]{\dotfill} \bigbreak}
% Pointilles
\newcommand{\Pointilles}[1]{%
    \vspace*{-\medskipamount}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{%
        \auxpts{}
    }
}

\SetEnumitemKey{cols}{before*=\begin{multicols}{#1},
        after*=\end{multicols}} % col for columns

\newif\iffirstItem\firstItemfalse% We need a toggle to track whether the item is first in the list or not

\SetEnumitemKey{dots}{before*={% This saves the standard definition of \item and then redefines at the end
        \let\olditem\item% save the standard definition of \item in a macro, \olditem
        \firstItemtrue% set the toggle for first item in the list to true
        \def\item{\iffirstItem\olditem\firstItemfalse\else \newline \Pointilles{#1} \mbox{}\olditem\fi}% new, temporary defition of \item
    },
    after*={%
        \ \newline \Pointilles{#1}\mbox{}% fill for final item in list
        \let\item\olditem% restore standard definition of \item
    }%
}
%==========================================
\begin{document}

\Pointilles{2}
\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[cols=4]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[dots=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[cols=2, dots=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[dots=2, cols=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually keys are set in the order that they're given. So, if you have two keys acting on the same mechanism (both `cols` and `dots` affect `before*` and `after*`), the last one will be the one that overrides the former ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `before*=<something>` and then `before*=<something else>`, the second declaration overrides the first.

You can set up a different key-value system for this purpose.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=0.5cm, bottom=1.6cm, left=0.7cm , right=0.7cm]{geometry}
\parindent0cm
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\auxpts}[0]{\makebox[\linewidth]{\dotfill} \bigbreak}
% Pointilles
\newcommand{\Pointilles}[1]{%
    \vspace*{-\medskipamount}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{%
        \auxpts{}
    }
}

\newlist{innanswers}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[innanswers]{
  label=\arabic*.,
  before=\maybemulticols\maybedots,
  after=\maybefinaldots\maybeendmulticols
}
\newenvironment{answers}[1][]
 {\setkeys{m45}{#1}\innanswers}
 {\endinnanswers}

\let\maybemulticols=\relax
\let\maybeendmulticols=\relax
\let\maybedots=\relax
\let\maybefinaldots=\relax
\def\doitemdots#1{%
  \let\olditem\item% save the standard definition of \item in a macro, \olditem
  \firstItemtrue% set the toggle for first item in the list to true
  \def\item{%
    \iffirstItem
      \olditem\firstItemfalse
    \else
      \newline\Pointilles{#1}\mbox{}\olditem
   \fi
  }% new, temporary defition of \item
}
\def\dofinaldots#1{%
  \ \newline \Pointilles{#1}\mbox{}% fill for final item in list
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{m45}{cols}{%
  \def\maybemulticols{\begin{multicols}{#1}}%
  \def\maybeendmulticols{\end{multicols}}%
}
\newif\iffirstItem\firstItemfalse

\define@key{m45}{dots}{%
  \def\maybedots{\doitemdots{#1}}
  \def\maybefinaldots{\dofinaldots{#1}}
}
\makeatother
%==========================================
\begin{document}

\Pointilles{2}
\hrule
\begin{answers}[cols=4]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{answers}
\hrule
\begin{answers}[dots=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{answers}
\hrule
\begin{answers}[cols=2, dots=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{answers}
\hrule
\begin{answers}[dots=2, cols=2]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
\end{answers}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works fine ! I added a new question to the post. I redefy `\Pointilles` to have a vertical skip parameter between the dots, but the question is, how to give this parameter a value in the list like a new key ?

Comment: @math45 Don't edit questions so as to invalidate existing answers. Ask a new one, please, using the proposed code.

Comment: Done, sorry, I'm not used to.